# Regex for string after string pattern

Tags: regex, go, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have a string like this (4 words separated by dot)

```
Exactfoobar.foobar-_nocaps.foobar-_nocaps.foobar-_caps
```

I need to write a regex to find the pattern as above.

1. There could be 4 or more fields separated by a dot
2. The first word should be exactly `Exactfoobar.`
3. The 2nd and 3rd word can't have caps but can have -_
4. The 4th word and so on can have caps with -_

I was thinking of using groups but its not working here:

```
^Exactfoobar\.([a-z0-9][a-z0-9_\-.])+([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_\-.])+$
```

How should I think about matching a string after another string. Is it possible?

Trying this in golang but cant seem to get the above regex right

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {

    var validID = regexp.MustCompile(`^ Exactfoobar\.([a-z0-9][a-z0-9_\-.])+([a-z0-9][a-z0-9_\-.])+$`)

    fmt.Println(validID.MatchString("Exactfoobar.somestring.some_other-string.someStringwithCaps"))


}
```

Result:

```
false
```

Thanks

Comment: why not split on the dot character then discard the first element (since it would always be `Exactfoobar`)? That way you don't need regex, which should be a lot faster and more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^Exactfoobar(?:\.[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_-]*){2}(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r5mufX/3)

- `^` - Start of string
- `Exactfoobar` - some word
- `(?:\.[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_-]*){2}` - two repetitions of a `.`, then a lowercase letter or digit and then 0+ lowercase letters or digits, `_` or `-`
- `(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)+` - 1 or more repetitions of

  - `\.` - dot
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - a letter or digit
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*` - 0+ letters, digits or `_` or `-`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: thanks @Wiktor! this worked like I was thinking. What does `?:` mean

Comment: @Sumitk See [What is a non-capturing group? What does (?:) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do).

Answer (score 0):

```
^Exactfoobar(?:\.[a-z0-9_\-]+){2}(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/PJ9V0L/1

Comment: This is a wrong solution, see [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8ebzJv/1). The words must begin with a letter or digit.

Comment: I guess you're right, although that wasn't an explicit requirement